# Home folder missed after "sudo mv -t /usr/local/src ~/"

Tags: bash, shell, mv

My home folder is missing after I run this command

```
sudo mv -t /usr/local/src ~/
```

How can I recover this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you moved your home dir to /usr/local/src .. just need to move it back:

```
$myuser="my_user_name"
sudo mv -t /ur/local/src/$myuser /home/ && chown -R $myuser:myuser ~
```

Unless it actually moved to root user home dir and you want:

```
$myuser="my_user_name"
sudo mv -t /ur/local/src/$myuser / && chown -R $myuser:myuser ~
```

Comment: `chown -R` should not be necessary...

Comment: I usd the -t accidently and I do't know the effect. It is recoverd now. Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad to be up service Colin Xie.